# Shared libraries and .h files

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, fpic

I have some doubt about how do programs use shared library.

When I build a shared library ( with `-shared -fPIC` switches) I make some functions available from an external program.
Usually I do a `dlopen()` to load the library and then `dlsym()` to link the said functions to some function pointers within my program.
This approach does not involve including any `.h` file.
Is there a way to avoid doing `dlopen()` & `dlsym()` and just including the `.h` of the shared library?

I *guess* this may be how C++ programs use code stored in system shared library, i.e - just including `stdlib.h` etc.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Nick, I think all the other answers are actually answering your question, which is how you link libraries, but the way you phrase your question suggests you have a misunderstanding of the difference between headers files and libraries.  They are not the same. You need *both*, and they are not doing the same thing.

Building an executable has two main phases, compilation (which turns your source into an intermediate form, containing executable binary instructions, but is not a runnable program), and linking (which combines these intermediate files into a single running executable or library).

When you do `gcc -c program.c`, you are compiling, and you generate `program.o`.  This step is where *headers* matter.  You need to `#include <stdlib.h>` in `program.c` to (for example) use `malloc` and `free`.  (Similarly you need `#include <dlfcn.h>` for `dlopen` and `dlsym`.)  If you don't do that the compiler will complain that it doesn't know what those names are, and halt with an error.  But if you do `#include` the header the compiler does *not* insert the code for the function you call into `program.o`.  It merely inserts a *reference* to them.  The reason is to avoid duplication of code: The code is only going to need to be accessed once by every part of your program, so if you needed further files (`module1.c`, `module2.c` and so on), even if they *all* used `malloc` you would merely end up with many references to a single copy of `malloc`.  That single copy is present in the standard *library* in either it's shared or static form (`libc.so` or `libc.a`) but these are not referenced in your source, and the compiler is not aware of them.

The linker *is*.  In the linking phase you do `gcc -o program program.o`.  The linker will then search all libraries you pass it on the command line and find the *single* definition of all functions you've called which are not defined in your own code.  That is what the `-l` does (as the others have explained): tell the linker the list of libraries you need to use.  Their names often have little to do with the headers you used in the previous step.  For example to get use of `dlsym` you need `libdl.so` or `libdl.a`, so your command-line would be `gcc -o program program.o -ldl`.  To use `malloc` or most of the functions in the `std*.h` headers you need `libc`, but because that library is used by *every* C program it is *automatically* linked (as if you had done `-lc`).

Sorry if I'm going into a lot of detail but if you don't know the difference you will want to.  It's very hard to make sense of how C compilation works if you don't.

One last thing: `dlopen` and `dlsym` are not the normal method of linking.  They are used for special cases where you want to dynamically determine what behavior you want based on information that is, for whatever reason, only available at runtime.  If you know what functions you want to call at compile time (true in 99% of the cases) you do not need to use the `dl*` functions.

Comment: you wrote: "For example to get use of dlsym you need libdl.so or libdl.a, so your command-line would be gcc -o program program.o -ldl."

How do I tell the linker if it has to use shared or static libraries?

Comment: Assuming you are using gcc?  The linker will prefer the shared over the static by default.  To make it prefer the static use the `-static` flag.

Comment: Incidentally, when in doubt: prefer to use shared libraries.  This is especially true for the system libraries.  There are definitely uses for static libraries but they are usually special cases.

Comment: looks like an answer to [Do I need to explicitly include a common header file(in an include path folder) used in shared library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043228/do-i-need-to-explicitly-include-a-common-header-filein-an-include-path-folder) also. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can link shared libraries like static one.  They are then searched for when launching the program.  As a matter of fact, by default -lXXX will prefer libXXX.so to libXXX.a.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the linker the proper instructions to link your shared library.

The shared library names are like libNAME.so, so for linking you should use -lNAME

Call it libmysharedlib.so and then link your main program as:

```
gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c -lmysharedlib
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) to build your project, you can use

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(targetname libraryname)
```

As in:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myprogram mylibrary)
```

To create the library "mylibrary", you can use

```
ADD_LIBRARY(targetname sourceslist)
```

As in:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(mylibrary ${mylibrary_SRCS})
```

Additionally, this method is cross-platform (whereas simply passing flags to gcc is not).

Answer (score 1):

- Shared libraries (`.so`) are object files where the actual source code of function/class/... are stored (in binary)
- Header files (`.h`) are files indicating (the reference) where the compiler can find function/class/... (in `.so`) that are required by the main code

Therefore, you need both of them.