# I've set the CPUPROFILE environment variable and linked -lprofiler. Why is gperftools not starting the profiler?

Tags: c++, ld, gperftools

According to the [gperftools documentation](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/cpuprofile.html), the profiler can be started using any of the following methods:

1. Setting the `CPUPROFILE` environment variable to the filename the profile information will be saved to
2. Doing the above, and also setting `CPUPROFILESIGNAL` and sending the appropriate signal to start or stop the sampling.
3. Calling `ProfilerStart(filename)` and `ProfileStop()` directly from your code

All three methods require that `libprofiler.so` be linked as well.

When I tried this, the third method worked, but when I merely set `CPUPROFILE`, no profiling information was generated.

Does not work:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
$ gcc foo.c -std=c99 -lprofiler -g && CPUPROFILE=foo.prof ./a.out
Hello, world!
$ ls foo.prof
ls: cannot access foo.prof: No such file or directory
```

Does work:

```
$ cat bar.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gperftools/profiler.h>

int main(void) {
    ProfilerStart("bogus_filename");
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    ProfilerStop();
}
$ gcc -std=c99 bar.c -lprofiler -g && CPUPROFILE=foo.prof ./a.out 
Hello, world!
PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 0/0/64
$ ls foo.prof
foo.prof
$ ls bogus_filename
ls: cannot access bogus_filename: No such file or directory
$ ./a.out
Hello, world!
PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 0/0/64
$ ls bogus_filename
bogus_filename
```

Note that `CPUPROFILE` is being read, since its value overrides the filename passed to `ProfileStart()` if set.

Comment: link to documentation is broken

Comment: @ofloveandhate Fixed.  Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the information needed to solve this is scattered across Stack Overflow, but it would have been useful to have it in one place, so now it is.  I've included references to the answers I found useful when solving this in case anyone is looking for further information.

In gperftools, the constructor for `CpuProfiler` checks for `CPUPROFILE` and calls `ProfilerStart(getenv("CPUPROFILE"))` if it's set (plus or minus a few other conditions).  A `CpuProfiler` is declared in `profiler.cc` to ensure that the function is called. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619974/how-exactly-does-gperftools-cpu-profiler-start) Naturally, this will only happen if the `libprofiler.so` is linked.

The following code reveals the issue:

```
$ cat baz.c 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gperftools/profiler.h>

int main(void) {
    volatile int i = 0;
    if (i) ProfilerStop();

    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -std=c99 baz.c -lprofiler -g && CPUPROFILE=foo.prof ./a.out 
Hello, world!
PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 0/0/64
```

`ProfileStop()` can never actually be called, but since `i` is volatile, the compiler can't optimize it away, and thus the linker needs to bring libprofiler in for the definition.  By default, `-lprofiler` was only bringing in the symbols that actually appeared in the program, which in the original case was none of them, so it didn't link the library at all, and `CpuProfiler()` never got called.

The fix is to pass the `--no-as-needed` flag to `ld` before linking `libprofiler.so`.  [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631161/force-to-link-against-unused-shared-library) This causes it to link the library whether or not it anything from it is used in the program (the ld man page seems to suggest that this should be the default behavior, but it wasn't working that way for me). The `--as-needed` flag is then passed to turn it back off once we've loaded what we need.  (As an aside, `--whole-archive` appears to be the equivalent option for static libraries [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767925/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-unreferenced-static-c-objects-from-a-library))

The compilation command to make the profiling work for the original file:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 foo.c -Wl,--no-as-needed,-lprofiler,--as-needed -g && CPUPROFILE=foo.prof ./a.out 
Hello, world!
PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 0/0/64
```

Comment: You can also just compile your program normally (i.e. no `-lprofiler` at all) and then use `LD_PRELOAD=.../libprofiler.so` to pull in the profiling machinery. This also eliminates any compile-time dependency on the profiler.