# Do I need to explicitly include a common header file(in an include path folder) used in shared library?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker, shared-libraries, header-files

I am using a shared library , say, `shr.so`. This has some header file, say, `shr_struct.h` with structures I need to use in my program , say, `main_prog.c`.

Do I need to keep a copy of `shr_struct.h` in my include path so that I can declare objects of structure types in `shr_struct.h` in `main_prog.c`?

Comment: Well, you do. That's the very purpose of header files.

Comment: So, I understand, the compiler searches for the structure definitions at compile time and hence cannot find the same from .so.This is because .so comes into picture only at link time. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If your `main_prog.c` depends on `shr_struct.h`, the compiler will need to know where this last file is located.

Now if the library is installed in the system "standard" library path, you may not have to explicitly add this path to the compiler command as it may be smart enough to search in the standard system path by itself.